# Al pedir la cabecera de mi request de JWT me devuelve nullo, String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization"), que puede ocasionar esto

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-security

Este es el principio de mi método de mi clase filter y quiero saber si algo puede generar que me devuelva un valor null: String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        
        if(requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            
            try {
                username = this.jwtUtils.extractUsername(jwtToken);
            }catch(ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException) {
                System.out.println("El token ha expirado");
            }catch(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println(requestTokenHeader); //null
            System.out.println("Token inválido, no empieza con bearer string");
        }
```

Comment: Pues para empezar, que lo estés mandando mal escrito. Has comprobado que el token lo envías correctamente?

Comment: @Benito-B, he programado validaciones en caso haya algún error, pero no me manda ninguno solo eso de null, no se como funciona bien ese request.getHeader

Comment: El getHeader no hace ninguna magia, solo obtiene el header que le indicas a partir del string... básicamente es un mapa de pares clave - valor, tú le das la clave y él te devuelve el valor... si da null hay dos posibilidades, o en algún sitio lo has escrito mal (en front por ejemplo) con lo cual la clave que le indicas realmente no existe, o tienes un filtro anterior al que estás mostrando en el que estás haciendo algo que hace que se pierdan los headers.